# Updating filenames with mysql database entry

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql table

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|    ID          |      picture       |
+----------------+--------------------+
|     10954      | picture/mypics.jpg |
+----------------+--------------------+
|     10759      | picture/mypics2.jpg|
+----------------+--------------------+
```

I need the existing filenames to be renamed to the ID for instance mypics.jpg renamed to 10954

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are they always prefixed with `picture/`?

Comment: Yes that is the location where the pictures are stored. They are all in the directory picture. So picture/mypics.jpg is the path to mypics.jp

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `following mysql table`
SET picture = CONCAT (
  SUBSTR (picture, 0, CHAR_LENGTH(picture) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(picture)),
  '/',
  ID
)
```

This replaces the part after the last slash with the value from the `ID` column. To my knowledge, MySQL has no function to find the last occurrence of a substring within a string, hence the funny construction with `CHAR_LENGTH`, `LOCATE` and `REVERSE`.

See [MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) for details.

Comment: Hello,maybe i am not clear enough. What i really need is to rename the actual file and not to update the mysql entry. So basically, i want to change the name of the existing files (which are represented by column picture to the column ID)

Comment: That cannot be done with MySQL. You have to look for some other technology, like shell scripts or PHP.